# Gnome-shell installed through updates

Tags: gnome, update-manager

Recently, I noticed that update manager was installing gnome-shell.

To be sure that is the case, I tried logging in with the Gnome option and I got to the Gnome 3 window manager.

Trying to remove it through `sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-shell` doesn't warn of the automatic removal of other packages, suggesting it is not a dependency issue.

I do not intend to use gnome-shell. Why was it installed automatically in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and type: `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-shell`

This will remove *Gnome-Shell* and its config files.

After that write: `sudo apt-get autoremove` just to be sure.

If you want to remove the session from the list, open a terminal, type `cd /usr/share/xsessions/ && ls`. The file should probably be something like **gnome.desktop** *or* **gnome-shell.desktop** I'm not sure.

Remove it with `sudo rm -rf gnome-shell.desktop`

Comment: How could I purge if I already removed gnome-shell?

Comment: use with caution: `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-shell*`
take a look at the list of packages that are going to be removed before proceeding.

Note the * in the end is a must.